# Количество комбинаций чисел при данных условиях

Tags: javascript, комбинаторика

Как найти **количество комбинаций чисел** из строки от 4 до 12 символов?

Условие:

> количество разделяющих точек - 3, символов между точками от 1 до 3,
> цифры местами не меняются.

Например:

```
Строка '1234'. 
Возможные комбинации: 
'1.2.3.4'
Количество комбинаций = '1.

Строка '12345'. 
Возможные комбинации:
'1.2.3.45',
'1.2.34.5',
'1.23.4.5',
'12.3.4.5'
Количество комбинаций = '4'
```

Comment: _Сочетания без повторений из n элементов по k_ где `n` - это количество дырок между цифрами, `k` - количество точек. Формула `C_{n}^{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot k!}`

Comment: Эта формула не учитывает ограничения " символов между точками от 1 до 3,"

Comment: @MBo, значит надо уточнить ее для таких случаев

Comment: Есть ли ограничение на количество цифр между точкой и началом или концом строки? Оно такое же, как и ограничение на количество между точками или его нет вообще?

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - алгоритм перебора с возвратом.

Фишка в том, чтобы **перебрать все** состояния и **отобрать** из них те, которые подходят под условия задачи. **Состояние** здесь - массив вида [1,1,0,1,...], где 1 - точка стоит, и 0 - точка не стоит для каждого "паза" между символами.

```js
const data = "0123456789";
const points_number = 3;
const data_length = data.length - 1;

const max_state_index = 1;
// 2 states: 0 - there isn't a point, 1 - there is a point
const EMPTY_SPACE_STATE_INDEX = 0;
const POINT_STATE_INDEX = 1;

let results = [];

function loop(index, limitIndex, loopLimit, currentState, callback) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= loopLimit; ++j) {
        currentState[index] = j;
        if (index !== limitIndex - 1) {
            loop(index + 1, limitIndex, loopLimit, currentState, callback);
        } else {
            callback(currentState);
        }
    }
}

function startLoop(limitIndex, loopLimit, callback) {
    loop(0, limitIndex, loopLimit, [], callback);
}

function isCorrectState(state) {
    let point_counter = 0;
    let last_point_index = -1;
    for (let shard of state) {
        if (shard === POINT_STATE_INDEX) {
            ++point_counter;
        }
    }
    if (point_counter !== points_number) {
        return false;
    }

    for (let j = 0; j < state.length; ++j) {
        if (state[j] === POINT_STATE_INDEX) {
            if (last_point_index >= 0) {
                let distance = Math.abs(j - last_point_index);
                const metric = points_number;
                if (distance > metric) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            last_point_index = j;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function calculateNewState(state) {
    const isCorrect = isCorrectState(state);
    if (isCorrect) {
        results.push([...state]);
    }
}

function printString(data, state) {
    let res = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        res += data[i] + (state[i] == POINT_STATE_INDEX ? "." : "");
    }
    console.log(res);
}


startLoop(data_length, max_state_index, calculateNewState);
for (let state of results) {
    printString(data, state);
}
console.log("Count: ", results.length);
```

Здесь константа **data_length** определяет длину входной строки. Её можно брать как stringData.length при вводе данных в виде строки.

Функция **loop** - цикл с переменной вложенностью.

Функция **startLoop** - функция для запуска цикла по переданным параметрам.

Функция **isCorrectState** - предикат определяющий, соответствует ли состояние условию задачи.

Функция **calculateNewState** - callback для переменного цикла, выбирает из новых состояний корректные и делает с ними что-нибудь (записывает в массив с результатами или считает.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, это не совсем честный алгоритм (скорее шулерская реализация принципа, предложенного [MaxLevs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/227383/maxlevs)), но пусть будет для коллекции.

Предлагаю такой порядок.

1. Представить комбинации в виде числа в бинарном представлении, где ноль будет представлять точку, а единица символ строки.
2. Получить всю последовательность чисел между минимальным вариантом (`1_0_1_0_1_0_1`) и максимальным (`111_0_111_0_111_0_111`).
3. Убрать из этой последовательности все неподходящие комбинации (где нулей больше трёх, где число единиц между нулями меньше 1 и больше 3, где нули не между единицами).
4. Распределить оставшуюся последовательность в группы по количеству единиц. Так мы получим объект массивов, где ключ — длина строки, а массив — все комбинации точек и символов в этой строке.
5. Для удобства добавить ещё один объект, где где ключ — длина строки, а значение — количество комбинаций.

```js
'use strict';

const min = 0b1_0_1_0_1_0_1;
const max = 0b111_0_111_0_111_0_111;

const validation = /^1{1,3}01{1,3}01{1,3}01{1,3}$/u;

const validCombinations =
  Array.from(
    Array(max - min + 1),
    (_, i) => (min + i).toString(2)
  )
  .filter(
    combination => validation.test(combination)
  )
  .reduce((acc, combination) => {
    const { length } = combination.replace(/0/ug, '');
    if (!acc[length]) acc[length] = [];
    acc[length].push(combination.replace(/0/ug, '.'));
    return acc;
  }, {});

const stringLengthToCombinationCount = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(validCombinations).map(([key, value]) => [key, value.length])
);

console.log(stringLengthToCombinationCount);
console.log(validCombinations);
```

Comment: Почему при увеличении входных данных количество комбинаций уменьшается?

Comment: Думаю, потому, что уменьшается пространство для маневра. 4 и 12 символов одинаково ограничены в соблюдении условий, например.

Comment: Это почему? Когда у тебя 4 символа (3 дырки), ты можешь поставить только 3 точки. Когда у тебя 12 символов (11 дырок), ты можешь,  *как минимум*, сдвигать эти 3 точки, получив 9 вариантов. И это даже без учёта максимального расстояния между точками в 3 символа. Тогда количество комбинаций снова возрастает.

Comment: При увеличении количества символов, количество комбинаций возрастает линейно (после 7-8 символов).

Comment: Приведите пример, как разделить 12 символов 3-мя точками с соблюдением условий иначе чем 111.111.111.111 - возможно, я неправильно что-то понял.

Comment: Хм. Я почему-то решил, что между точкой и началом/концом строки тоже может быть только от 1 до 3 символов. Если это не так, моё решение и правда неправильное. Я  попросил автора вопроса, чтобы он уточнил.

Comment: Автор вопроса потерялся в астрале ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: На данный момент указано "*между* точками". Начало и конец - не точки. Формулировка говорит об этом. Зависит от внимательности автора к своему вопросу

Comment: Наверное, я подсознательно воспринял это как задачу на комбинации из IPv4 адресов)

Comment: Кстати, да, вполне может быть.

Answer (score -1):

Рекурсивный подсчёт.
n - длина строки, k - количество частей, m - максимум между точками.

Сначала уменьшаем размерность задачи, вычтя 1 из m и всех частей (т.о. пустые части возможны).

Потом подставляем возможные размеры очередной части и рекурсивно решаем для оставшихся частей

Код (спасибо CbIPoK2513 за перевод с Python) выдаёт 19 - проверяем:
6 перестановок 3 3 2 2
12 перестановок 3 2 2 1
1 вариант 2 2 2 2

```js
function cp(n, k, m) {
  if (k == 0)
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    else return 0;
  res = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(n + 1, m + 1); i++)
    res += cp(n - i, k - 1, m);
  return res;
}

function countparts(n, k, m) {
  return cp(n - k, k, m - 1);
}

console.info(countparts(8, 4, 3));
```

Comment: Это какой язык? Нужен JS

Comment: Вот этот же код на JS - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CbIPoK2513/78gnf4hd/)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 О, спасибо, а то мой перевод не работал правильно - то ли let перед i упустил....

Comment: @Gelix Ford Ну как, JS помог?